# Using sizeof with sprintf/vsnprintf corrupts text

Tags: c

I'm attempting to avoid using fixed buffer sizes with things like sprintf and friends (security reasons), however, when I change it to use a sizeof for arg2 -> arg1, my programs text output is corrupted / doesn't display correctly / missing certain parts.

Specifically, ie:

```
vsnprintf(putbuf, LARGE_BIG_BUFFER_SIZE, format, args);
```

to

```
vsnprintf(putbuf, sizeof putbuf, format, args);
```

My text output is all corrupted / short with the simple sizeof change. Am I missing something?

original function:

```
to_screen(const char *format,...)
{
        if (window_display && format) {
                va_list args;
                va_start(args, format);
                vsnprintf(putbuf, LARGE_BIG_BUFFER_SIZE, format, args);
                va_end(args);
        }
}
```

Comment: How and where is `putbuf` declared?

Comment: You should also check the return value of the print function.

Comment: sizeof will only return size of an array in bytes if putbuf is an array. Even in that case if it was integer array of size say 10, sizeof would return 40 (assuming 32bit machine with int size 4).

Comment: putbuf = new_malloc(LARGE_BIG_BUFFER_SIZE + 1);

Comment: being set up in the chain, ie: putbuf = my_malloc(LARGE_BIG_BUFFER_SIZE + 1);

Comment: The argument to vsnprintf includes space for the terminating NUL so you don't need the + 1 ... not that it hurts, but it's misleading and causes one to wonder why it's there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put in your code somewhere:

```
printf ("size is %d\n", sizeof (putbuf));
```

If it's a *pointer,* you'll probably get four or eight since that'll be the size of a pointer on your system (four or eight will be common ones at the moment but it all depends on the size of your pointers).

Remember that arrays will decay into pointers in the vast majority of cases.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fn (char x[]) {
    printf ("size in fn = %zd\n", sizeof (x));
}

int main (void) {
    char x[100];
    printf ("size in main = %zd\n", sizeof (x));
    fn (x);
    return 0;
}
```

output this on my system:

```
size in main = 100
size in fn = 4
```

If you want to pass the *actual* size information, you need to do it explicitly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fn1 (char x[]) {
    printf ("size in fn1 = %zd\n", sizeof (x));
}

void fn2 (char x[], size_t szx) {
    printf ("size in fn2 = %zd\n", szx);
}

int main (void) {
    char x[100];
    printf ("size in main = %zd\n", sizeof (x));
    fn1 (x);
    fn2 (x, sizeof (x));
    return 0;
}
```

or, alternatively, for allocated memory:

```
#define SZ 512
int main (void) {
    char *x = malloc (SZ);   // warning, may fail, irrelevant here.
    printf ("size in main = %zd\n", sizeof (x));
    fn2 (x, SZ);
    free (x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'size is 8' is what I'm seeing. Should I just leave the fixed buffer size in the code?

Comment: @user1621581 If you pass the buffer as a parameter to function in the form int [] i.e. int array, you can still use size of. Keep in mind that size of returns number of bytes and not number of elements. So if you have an integer array of size 10, sizeof array would return 40 (assuming 32 bit integer)

Comment: @user1621581 What you should do is use the same value to allocate putbuf as you pass to vsnprintf. e.g., `#define PUTBUF_SIZE 576 ... putbuf = malloc(PUTBUF_SIZE) ... vnsprintf(putbuf, PUTBUF_SIZE ...` ... if the size of putbuf is variable, then use the variable.

Comment: Not that it matters, by putbuf is simply 'static char *putbuf = NULL;'

Comment: @user1621581, I hope you're actually allocating some memory for that before using it for anything, yes?

Comment: Yes. In a previous function, I'm simply doing this, ie: putbuf = my_malloc(LARGE_BIG_BUFFER_SIZE + 1);

Comment: @user1621581, then you need to pass _that_ in as the length, as per my final code block.

Answer (score 2):

probably `sizeof` evaluates to the width of a pointer to your buffer, not to the size of the actual buffer.

---

See [this article](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=vsnprintf) for another suggestion to cope with this:

> To allocate a sufficiently large string and print into it (code correct for both glibc 2.0 and glibc 2.1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char * make_message(const char *fmt, ...) {
  /* Guess we need no more than 100 bytes. */
  int n, size = 100;
  char *p, *np;
  va_list ap;

  if ((p = malloc (size)) == NULL)
    return NULL;

  while (1) {
    /* Try to print in the allocated space. */
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    n = vsnprintf (p, size, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    /* If that worked, return the string. */
    if (n > -1 && n < size)
       return p;
    /* Else try again with more space. */
    if (n > -1)    /* glibc 2.1 */
       size = n+1; /* precisely what is needed */
    else           /* glibc 2.0 */
       size *= 2;  /* twice the old size */
    if ((np = realloc (p, size)) == NULL) {
       free(p);
       return NULL;
    } else {
       p = np;
    }
  }
}
```