# malloc not allocating the correct number of bytes

Tags: c, malloc

gcc (GCC) 4.7.0 c89

I am allocating memory using the following:

```
db_data_size = 32;
db->db_data[i]->name = malloc(db_data_size);

(gdb) p db_data_size
$24 = 32
(gdb) p sizeof(db->db_data[i]->name)
$25 = 8
(gdb) n
205   db->db_data[i]->email = malloc(db_data_size);
(gdb) p sizeof(db->db_data[i]->name)
$26 = 8
```

In the debugger I get 8 bytes instead of the 32 bytes I think should have been allocated.

My structure is:

```
struct data {
    int id;
    int set;
    char *name;
    char *email;
};

struct database {
    struct data **db_data;
    size_t database_rows;
    size_t database_data_size;
};
```

The only think I can think of is that a char* is 8 bytes, and that is what I am getting. However, in malloc I have explicity asked for 32 bytes.

Comment: This is a common mistake by rookies, apparently; other example was posted quite recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598839/using-sizeof-with-sprintf-vsnprintf-corrupts-text

Comment: More generally, the rookie mistake is assuming that you know what something does from its name ;-)

Comment: I have allocated a byte size of 32: db_data_size = 32;
db->db_data[i]->name = malloc(db_data_size);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sizeof(db->db_data[i]->name)
```

tells you the size of

```
char *name;
```

which is the size of a pointer (to char). It does not tell you the size of the allocated block; if you need to remember that, you must store it separately.

So `8` is the correct answer for a pointer on a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is a compile time operator, which gives the size of a data type. It won't tell you the size of the allocated block of memory, but instead the size of a `char*`, which on your 64-bit system is 8 bytes.

It's up to you to keep track of the size of the allocated block.